# NodeJS (Express 4) + i18n + underscore: issue with translations in templates

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, internationalization, underscore.js

Using: NodeJS (Express 4) + i18n + underscore.

I want to bind and translate an Underscore template in NodeJS (Express 4).

- Binding works fine.
- Translations work fine outside of the template.

But I have an issue with the translation inside the template: Underscore doesn't understand the syntax <%= __('translation key') %>: 
`[ReferenceError: __ is not defined]`

Here is my NodeJS code:

```
var express = require('express'),
app     = express(),
cons    = require('consolidate'),
i18n    = require('i18n');
_       = require('underscore'),

// setup i18n
app.use(i18n.init);
i18n.configure({
    locales: ['en', 'fr'],
    directory:'./app/locales',
    defaultLocale: 'en'
});

// setup hbs
app.engine('html',cons.underscore);
app.set('views', './app/views');
app.set('view engine', 'html');

// translation test ok
console.log('Translation test: ' + i18n.__('hello'));

// rendering template generates error
app.render('test.html', {hello: 'Welcome !'}, function(err, html){
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log(html);
    }
});
```

This is my Undescore template 'test.html':

```
<h1><%= hello %></h1>
<p><%= __('hello') %></p>
```

And the JSON i18n file for english 'en.json':

```
{
    "hello": "hello my friend"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're missing register a public helper for views. Try to define in your NodeJS app:

```
var hbs = require('hbs');

hbs.registerHelper('__', function () {
   return i18n.__.apply(this, arguments);
});
```

And then in your template:

```
<p>{{{__ 'hello'}}}</p>
```